# boost::python hybrid embedding/exposing: how do I get globals() and see my own module?

Tags: c++, python, boost-python, embedding, global

I'm using boost::python to do a hybrid C++/python application: the C++ app calls a collection of python scripts, which in turn use the C++ program's functions, classes, etc., exposed as python objects. (Python 2.x.)

`BOOST_PYTHON_MODULE(MyModule)` exposes the C++ to python as expected.

My initialization code:

```
Py_Initialize();
initMyModule(); // import MyModule

namespace bpl = boost::python;
```

Now I want my C++ code to get at `MyModule`, too. In python, you just write `globals()['MyModule']`. But this (and things like it) don't work in C++:

```
bpl::object globals = bpl::eval("globals()");
```

This fails at run-time with

> `File "<string>", line 1, in <module>; NameError: name 'globals' is not defined`

As an aside, I see many examples of setting up `__main__` like this:

```
bpl::object m = bpl::import("__main__");
bpl::dict g = m.attr("__dict__"); // like locals(), but not globals()
```

This doesn't fail, and gives locals, but according to the [Py_Initialize docs](http://docs.python.org/2/c-api/init.html#initializing-and-finalizing-the-interpreter), `__main__` is already set up. And it doesn't let you see globals, where you'd find your imported module.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need the explicit `bpl::import("__main__");`.

Here are the globals:

```
bpl::dict globals()
   {
   bpl::handle<> mainH(bpl::borrowed(PyImport_GetModuleDict()));
   return bpl::extract<bpl::dict>(bpl::object(mainH));
   }
```

Since everything is managed by smart pointers, returning and manipulating `bpl::dict` directly works fine.

```
bpl::object myMod = globals()["MyModule"];
globals()["myNewGlobal"] = 88;
```